# Predicting Classifications with some Words not in the training set (Naive Bayes)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, naivebayes

I am created a Naive Bayes model to predict if the outcome is 'negative' or 'positive'. The problem I am having is running the model on a new set of data with some of the words not in the model. The error I receive for predicting a new data set is :

ValueError: Expected input with 6 features, got 4 instead

I read that I would have to put a Laplace Smoother in my model and Bernoulli() already has a default alpha of 1. What else can I do to fix my error? Thank you

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import textblob as TextBlob



#scikit
comments = list(['happy','sad','this is negative','this is positive', 'i like this', 'why do i hate this'])
classes = list(['positive','negative','negative','positive','positive','negative'])


# preprocess creates the term frequency matrix for the review data set
stop = stopwords.words('english')
count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer =u'word',stop_words = stop, ngram_range=(1, 3))
comments = count_vectorizer.fit_transform(comments)
tfidf_comments = TfidfTransformer(use_idf=True).fit_transform(comments)


# preparing data for split validation. 60% training, 40% test
data_train,data_test,target_train,target_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(tfidf_comments,classes,test_size=0.2,random_state=43)
classifier = BernoulliNB().fit(data_train,target_train)

#new data
comments_new = list(['positive','zebra','george','nothing'])
comments_new = count_vectorizer.fit_transform(comments_new)
tfidf_comments_new = TfidfTransformer(use_idf=True).fit_transform(comments_new)

classifier.predict(tfidf_comments_new)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not fit a new estimator on the new data using `fit_transform`, but use the previously build count_vectorizer, just using `transform`. That will ignore all words that were not in the dictionary.

I disagree with Maxim: While this doesn't make a difference for CountVectorizer, using TfidfTransformer on the joined dataset will leak information from the test set to the training set, which you need to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a count matrix from 'comments' words. While creating count matrix you **must** use all of possible words you will encounter in your problem.Imagine the simpler case when you create a membership matrix. Each column states for specific word, each row - for specific example from dataset (for example, email text). Matrix holds 0 if specific word is not in the example, and 1 if it is in example. Obviously, if you have built such matrix for emails which hold, for example, 100 different words, the matrix will have 100 of columns. But if after that you will try to use trained classifier against new data in which you will have some new word, which wasn't in the training set - it will just fail. Since there was no column in original matrix to hold values for these new word. So once again, during vectorization of text you must provide all terms you will ever face in train and test datasets.

So instead of calling CountVectorizer and tfidfTransformer against 'comments' you must join both comments and comments_new into one list and call CountVectorizer and tfidfTransformer against the joined list.